# The right format for textile printing

Tags: file-format, digital-printing

What is he right type of file for printing on textile?. Depending on the design, i normally i save my artwork as PDS or AI file.

I came across someone that does it always as bitmap, which is new to me as a fact.

Is this a better option for textile printing? what about TIFF? would that be also good?

Thanks.

Comment: The best format would be what your printing company is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Textile ***usually*** operates the same as traditional printing.

I would always send a print-ready `.pdf` or `.eps`. Usually I never send the source files over unless the manufacturer requests them.